# Getting computed NA column values in julia DataFrames that respond to dropna

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm trying to use `NA` as a result to indicate that the 
computed value for a given DataFrame "row" is meaningless
(or perhaps can't be computed). How do I get a column with computed `NA`s that still responds to `dropna`?

Example:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = [1, 0, 2, 3], C = [5, 4, 3, 3])

# A value of 0 in column B should yield a foo of NA
function foo(d)
  if d[:B] == 0
    return NA
  end
  return d[:B] ./ d[:C] # vectorized to work with `by`
end

# What I'm looking for is something equivalent to this list
# comprehension, but that returns a DataFrame or DataArray
# since normal Arrays don't respond to `dropna`

comprehension = [foo(frame) for frame in eachrow(df)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this...

```
using DataFramesMeta
result = @with(df, map(foo, :B, :C)) 

#=> DataArray{Any,1}: [0.2, NA, 0.667, 1.0]
```

...**if** `foo` can be re-written to reference individual values rather than an entire `DataFrame`:

```
function foo(b, c)
  if b == 0
    return NA
  end
  return b / c
end
```

Similarly, if you want a new DataFrame containing the new column, use `@transform`:

```
tdf = @transform(df, foo = map(foo, :B, :C))
#=>4x4 DataFrame
#  | Row | A | B | C | foo      |
#  |-----|---|---|---|----------|
#  | 1   | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0.2      |
#  | 2   | 2 | 0 | 4 | NA       |
#  | 3   | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0.666667 |
#  | 4   | 4 | 3 | 3 | 1.0      |
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to extend `Base.convert` and `DataArrays.dropna` so that `dropna` can handle normal `Vector`s:

```
using DataFrames

function Base.convert{T}(::Type{DataArray}, v::Vector{T})
  da = DataArray(T[],Bool[])
  for val in v
    push!(da, val)
  end
  return da
end

function DataArrays.dropna(v::Vector)
  return dropna(convert(DataArray,v))
end
```

Now the example should work as expected:

```
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = [1, 0, 2, 3], C = [5, 4, 3, 3])

# A value of 0 in column B should yield a foo of NA
function foo(d)
  if d[:B] == 0
    return NA
  end
  return d[:B] / d[:C]
end

comprehension = [foo(frame) for frame in eachrow(df)]  

dropna(comprehension) #=> Array{Any,1}: [0.2, 0.667, 1.]
```

Even without the extended `dropna`, the extended `convert` allows the comprehension to be inserted into the DataFrame as a new DataArray column, preserving `NA`s and their appropriate dropping behavior:

```
conv = convert(DataArray, comprehension)
insert!(df, size(df, 2) + 1, conv, :foo)
#=> 4x4 DataFrame
#  | Row | A | B | C | foo      |
#  |-----|---|---|---|----------|
#  | 1   | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0.2      |
#  | 2   | 2 | 0 | 4 | NA       |
#  | 3   | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0.666667 |
#  | 4   | 4 | 3 | 3 | 1.0      |

typeof(df[:foo]) #=> DataArray{Any,1} (constructor with 1 method)
dropna(df[:foo]) #=> Array{Any,1}: [0.2, 0.667, 1.]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit tricky since rows of dataframes are awkward objects.  For example, I would think this would be entirely reasonable:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = [1, 0, 2, 3], C = [5, 4, 3, 3])

# A value of 0 in column B should yield a foo of NA
function foo(d)
    if d[:B] == 0
    return NA
  end
  return d[:B] / d[:C] # vectorized to work with `by`
end
comp = DataArray(Float64,4)
map!(r->foo(r), eachrow(df))
```

but this results in

```
`map!` has no method matching map!(::Function, ::DFRowIterator{DataFrame})
```

However, if you just want to do a `by` that doesn't always return a row then you can do something like this:

```
using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = [1, 0, 2, 3], C = [5, 4, 3, 3])

# A value of 0 in column B returns an empty array
function foo(d)
    if d[1,:B] == 0
        return []
  end
    return d[1,:B] / d[1,:C] #Plan on only getting a single row in the by
end

by(df, [:A,:B,:C]) do d
    foo(d)
end
```

which results in

```
3x4 DataFrame
| Row | A | B | C | x1       |
|-----|---|---|---|----------|
| 1   | 1 | 1 | 5 | 0.2      |
| 2   | 3 | 2 | 3 | 0.666667 |
| 3   | 4 | 3 | 3 | 1.0      |
```

Comment: A new DataFrame with dropped rows looks like a useful strategy in many cases, but it doesn't fit my desire to keep `NA`s in the result. I want to keep the `NA`s in the column so they poison succeeding element-wise calculations involving that column, but still have the ability to drop them when that's appropriate (such as computing column mean).